# Angular 6: continuously execute http request inside ngAfterContentChecked after receive data from parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm from React.js

I have a problem where Angular makes `HTTP` requests forever inside `ngAfterContentChecked` after receiving data from the parent component

I cannot make a request inside `ngAfterContentInit` because I need to wait for the parent to finish making a request

I just want it to call once right after getting data from the parent

in React.js normally I make a request inside `componentWillReceiveProps`

While in Angular I do this.

Parent component:

```
//codes...
groupId = '';
//codes...

ngOnInit() {
  const id = '23esaddq3sdasd';
  this.dataService.getUser(id).subscribe(data => {
    //codes...
    this.groupId = data.groupId;
    //codes...
  });
}
```

Child component:

```
data = [];
@Input() groupId;
fetch;

ngAfterContentChecked() {
  if (this.groupId) {
    const res = this.dataService.getGroupMembers(this.groupId).subscribe(data => 
      this.data = data;
      this.fetch = 'done';
    });
    if (this.fetch === 'done') {
      res.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

I try to `unsubscribe` it but still continuously execute the code.

Anybody, please help me

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ngAfterContentChecked, you can use ngOnChanges() which get trigged when parent pass data to child component using @input().

ngAfterContentChecked lifecycle will be used if you have projection content 'ng-content' and access any DOM on parent Component change detection.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `ngOnChanges` because that is fired every time the @Input value changes.

The full signature for `ngOnChanges` is:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void
```

So check the changes object to see if it contains a change to your @Input and that the value is as expected and THEN make the HTTP request like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.groupId != null && fetch !== 'done') {
    const res = this.dataService.getGroupMembers(this.groupId).subscribe(data => 
      this.data = data;
      this.fetch = 'done';
    });
  }
}
```

There is no need to unsub because subs to HTTP requests will complete automatically. To prove this do this:

```
    const res = this.dataService.getGroupMembers(this.groupId).subscribe(data => 
      this.data = data;
      this.fetch = 'done';
    },
    err => {
      console.log('I errored');
    },
    () => {
      console.log('I completed and won't fire again');
    });
```

PS The reason ngAfterContentChecked is firing like crazy is that it executes extremely regularly.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I would go something like this:

1. Parent trigger http, you need to set a flag like `isLoading = true`
2. In the .html use `*ngIf="!isLoading "` to that child component
3. After parent done receiving request, set `isLoading = false`
4. This will make the child component rendered, and you can use `ngOnInit` hook inside child component to receive data from parent
5. After child component receive inputs from parent in `ngOnInit` you can trigger your http

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ngOnChanges, you can use setter and getter which get trigged only when parent pass data to child component using @input().

ngOnChanges runs always when something is changed in any of the parent or child component.

```
  private _name;
  get name() { return this._name };
  @Input() set name(val: string) {
      if (val) {
          this._name = val;
          this.getGreetings(this.name)
      }
  };
  greetings = '';
  processing = false;
  constructor(){}

  getGreetings(name){
      this.processing = true;
      setTimeout(()=>{
          this.greetings = 'Hi.. '+name+', How are you';
          this.processing = false;
      },2000)
  }
```

Working demo link :- [Ckick Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/setter-and-getter-input?embed=1&file=src/app/child/child.component.ts&view=editor)